# Regarding android app development

Tags: android, xml

Can anyone tell me more about the line- android:id = "@+id/enter_message" ?
where enter_message is a string. Why do we use '@+' before the 'id'?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#TextInput - Their basic tutorials cover this is prefect detail.

Comment: It creates new id.   If you don't use +, you are telling that you are going to use an id that is already declared using another @+id

Answer (score 5):

From Android official documentation:

ID

"Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely identify the View within the tree. When the application is compiled, this ID is referenced as an integer, but the ID is typically assigned in the layout XML file as a string, in the id attribute. This is an XML attribute common to all View objects (defined by the View class) and you will use it very often. The syntax for an ID, inside an XML tag is:"

```
android:id="@+id/my_button"
```

The at-symbol (@) at the beginning of the string indicates that the XML parser should parse and expand the rest of the ID string and identify it as an ID resource. The plus-symbol (+) means that this is a new resource name that must be created and added to our resources (in the R.java file)

Read more here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: which one is the resource here? id or the tag under which this syntax comes?  I notices that all tags dont have this for eg: 
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />

Comment: why doesnt the button tag have an id?

Comment: The ID tag is optional.

Answer (score 0):

The @ signifies that it is a reference to a value. The + signifies that you're adding a value to be referenced. Other than that, the choice of those particular symbols by Google is completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

The `@+id/enter_message` sign means that you are adding an ID "enter_message" to the list of android resource ids. `@id/enter_message` means that you are referring to an id that has already been created and is present in the resource ids.